# Descent of isomorphisms between irreducible closed subschemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, algebraic-cycles, descent

Let $S$ be an affine scheme, $X$ be a projective $S$-scheme, $W,Z\to X$ two reduced, irreducible closed $S$-subschemes, flat over $S$. Let $S'\to S$ be a faithfully flat map, with $S'$ affine.

Assume there exists an $S'$-isomorphism $g: W_{S'}\xrightarrow{\simeq} Z_{S'}$, commuting with the closed immersions into $X_{S'}$.

When does there exist an $S$-morphism $f : W\to Z$ such that $f_{S'} = g$, and (hence) $f$ is an $S$-isomorphism?

Comment: This follows from the fact that X ↦ {closed subschemes of X} is an fpqc sheaf, which in turn follows from fpqc descent of quasi-coherent sheaves.

Comment: The hypothesis is that $W_{S'}$ and $Z_{S'}$ agree as closed subschemes as of $X_{S'}$. This means that their ideals in $\mathcal{O}_X$ become equal when we pass from $S$ to $S'$. As $S'\to S$ is faithfully flat, this means that they are equal. No need for Hilbert schemes or fpqc sheaves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$W,Z\to X$ are classified by two points $s,s'\in\text{Hilb}_{X/S}(S)$. Here I mean the Hilbert functor, ie. I am not using its representability.

Since the Hilbert functor is an fpqc sheaf (ie. with no need of a sheafification) and $S'\to S$ is an fpqc cover, the map

$$\text{Hilb}_{X/S}(S)\to (S'\to S)^{-1}_{\rm fpqc}\text{Hilb}_{X/S}(S')$$
is injective.

We have $(S'\to S)^{-1}_{\rm fpqc}\text{Hilb}_{X/S} = \text{Hilb}_{X_{S'}/S'}$, and so if $s,s'$ agree in $\text{Hilb}_{X_{S'}/S'}(S')$ under the above map, we have $s = s'$ in $\text{Hilb}_{X/S}(S)$.

Am I missing something?